# Checking Self=nil in virtual method, with parameters

Tags: delphi, access-violation, null

I have two classes: one base class an one derived class
The base class defines a virtual method with a parameter:

```
function ToName(MsgIfNil:string=''); virtual;
```

The derived class redefines the method:

```
function ToName(MsgIfNil:string=''); reintroduce;
```

The implementation of both methods is similar to this code:

```
function TBaseClass.ToName(MsgIfNil:string)
begin
  if (Self=nil) then
    Result := MsgIfNil
  else
    Result := Self.SomeProperty;
end;
```

The issue is that:

1) If I do not reintroduce the method in the derived class, but use the regular override keyword, any call to this method triggers an access violation

2) When I call the method from an object being nil, and the presumed class of the objet is TBaseObject, it crashes (AV) instead of calling the base virtual method

If no parameter is defined in the method, the right method is called, without any AV. It works well even if the method in the derived class is overriden.

Note that the above solution works well with objects of any class derived from TBaseClass

**How can I define a virtual method that can be called with Self=nil, can be virtual and use parameters?**

I certainly must enhance my understanding of internal virtual method call plumbering...

Note: Calling on a nil object is legitimate in my use cases. It is not used to hide exceptions, but to report on non linked objects. 
Example: myEdit.Text := APerson.Manager.ToName('No manager defined');

Thanks for any advise on a proper solution

Using Delphi 2010 with upd5

---

Edit: Adding a more complete example of code that triggers an AV

```
TBaseClass = class(TObject)
private
  FMyName: string;
public
  property MyName: string read FMyName;
  function ToName(MsgIfNil:string=''):string; virtual;
end;

TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass)
private
  FSpecialName: string;
public
  property SpecialName:string read FSpecialName;
  function ToName(MsgIfNil:string=''):string; reintroduce;
end;

TBaseClass.ToName(MsgIfNil:string):string;
begin
   if (Self=nil) then
     Result := MsgIfNil
   else
     Result := MyName;
end;

TDerivedClass.ToName(MsgIfNil:string):string;
begin
  if (Self=nil) then
    Result := MsgIfNil
  else
    Result := SpecialName;
end;

// Now a sample program

var
  aPerson: TBaseClass;
  aSpecialist: TDerivedClass;

begin

aPerson := TBaseClass.Create;
aPerson.MyName := 'a person';
aSpecialist := TDerivedClass.Create;
aSpecialist.SpecialName := 'a specialist';

aSpecialist := nil; // For example sake, never do this in my use case :)
// This works here,
// but triggers an AV if ToName is marked as override instead of reintroduce
ShowMessage('Name of the specialist: '+aSpecialist.ToName('No specialist!'));

aPerson := nil;
// This triggers an AV, TBaseClass.ToName is never called
ShowMessage('Name of the person: '+aPerson.ToName('No person!'));

end;
```

The above code may not compile, this is only intended to be a more complete example

**Takeway**

I now understand that VMT is linked to the object reference and, regardless of the object class, calling a virtual method on a nil object is not possible (the object will not even look at its declared type to get the matching address of the ToName method)

I accepted hvd's solution because it is really effective for methods that must check vs nil (only one base method to add).

Thanks for all answers,

Comment: In 1 case: you try to call inherited of nil. Of course you will get AV. In 2 case: very interesting, how do you call Method of NIL object? Instantly you will get an AV. Object must be valid before call any method. Maybe you need CLASS methods?

Comment: Hi. For case 2, I have a method TDerivedClass.Manager:TBaseClass; and a call to SomeValidObject.Manager.ToName('no manager defined'), were the Manager method returns nil. I would expect TBaseClass.ToName to be called then, but it triggers AV

Comment: Please add full code of a small sample that AVs. I think your code should not AV, but I do understand your use case, and am willing to help you with it. Virtual methods should not be callable on nil instances (because of the VMT lookup you need an instance), but going along the lines that Free does call Destroy you can solve it.

Comment: @Jeroen: Sure, I'll add a more complete example. I had looked at Free method. It works because no argument is provided, same for me if ToName has no argument. The problem is raised when using an argument.

Comment: @user315561 For ex. If Manager method returns NIL instead of object, Just check result before call ToName:  O := TDerivedClass.Manager; if Assigned(O) then O.ToName();

Comment: @user315561 No, it's unrelated to whether the function has an argument. It works with `Free` because `Free` is nonvirtual. It merely calls a virtual method.

Comment: @Marcodor: This coding method was set to avoid having to check nil each and every time, for some controlled use cases. I could not use this method at all but the goal of the question is to know if/how to continue using it...

Comment: "How can I define a virtual method that can be called with Self=nil, can be virtual and use parameters?" You can't.

Comment: @user315561 Anyway you check it for nil. You just changed the PLACE. Why to check it for nil in method EVERYCASE, for example if I'm sure that object is valid? Why Borland did not check object validity in every function? Let's say TForm.Show(), if (Self = nil) then ShowMessage('Nothing to show :) '); BAD logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling a virtual method on `nil` doesn't make sense: `virtual` means "check the class type to see which method to call". There is no class type, so there is no method to call.

What you can do is create a nonvirtual method that calls a virtual method:

```
// TBase
public:
    function ToName(MsgIfNil: string = ''): string;
protected:
    function ToNameImpl: string; virtual;

// TDerived
protected:
    function ToNameImpl: string; override;

function TBase.ToName(MsgIfNil: string): string;
begin
  if (Self=nil) then
    Result := MsgIfNil
  else
    Result := ToNameImpl;
end;

function TBase.ToNameImpl: string;
begin
  Result := MyName;
end;

function TDerived.ToNameImpl: string;
begin
  Result := MyDerivedName;
end;
```

This ensures that `ToNameImpl`, the virtual method, is only called when `Self` is not `nil`.

Edit: By the way, this is exactly what the nonvirtual `TObject.Free` does to call the virtual `TObject.Destroy`.

Comment: When Destroy is called, object still exist. That is not the user315561's situation.

Comment: @Torbins See the example of `APerson.Manager.ToName('No manager defined');`: either `APerson.Manager` is `nil`, in which case the virtual method won't be called with my answer, or `APerson.Manager` is a valid object, and there is no problem calling the virtual method. The question isn't about making `x.Foo` work after `x.Free`, it's about making `x.Foo` work after `x := nil`.

Comment: @hvd: But ToName should also be virtual, right? If not, I'm not able to call it from any derived class. And if its virtual, it may crash like it does currently?

Comment: In my opinion your method is just a workaround to overcome bad design. In real production code such things shouldn't be used more than once.

Comment: @user315561 No, `ToName` shouldn't be virtual. You are able to call it from derived classes, and it will call the derived class's `ToNameImpl`.

Comment: +1, This works fine. Just remove the abstract in the `TBase.ToNameImpl` since the OP is actually using this.

Comment: @LURD Thanks, after re-reading the question I see it, and have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I define a virtual method that can be called with Self=nil, can be virtual and use parameters?

That can't be done in delphi, because you will need a VMT for a virtual method call. And Nil-objects don't have VMT.

> Calling on a nil object is legitimate in my use cases.

You will have to rethink your logic. For example you can create some sort of "Empty" object. In this case your APerson.Manager will return this special object, which is an ancestor of TBaseClass with special behaviour. Some sample code:

```
TManager = class
//...
function GetSalary: integer; virtual;
procedure SetSalary(ASalary: integer) virtual;
end;

TEmptyManager = class(TManager)
//...
function GetSalary: integer; override;
procedure SetSalary(ASalary: integer) override;
end;
//...
function TManager.GetSalary: integer;
begin
//Some calculations here
end;

procedure TManager.SetSalary(ASalary: integer);
begin
//Some work here
end;

function TEmptyManager.GetSalary: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TEmptyManager.SetSalary(ASalary: integer) override;
begin 
  //Some sort of safety belt
  raise EException.Create('You can''t work with empty manager');
end;

var
  EManager: TEmptyManager = Nil;
//Since we won't work with empty manager, one instance will be enough
function EmptyManager: TManager;
begin
  if not Assigned(EManager) then
    EManager := TEmptyManager.Create;

  Result := EManager;
end;
//...
function TPerson.GetManager: TManager;
begin
  if SomeCondition then
    Result := FManager
  else
    Result := EmptyManager;
end;
```

Comment: In the example, it's clear that no random pointer value is returned. Either nil or a valid object is returned.

Comment: Pointer in VMT table won't be Nil.

Comment: What? The VMT table associated with a nil object reference? There is no such thing.

Comment: Exactly. That is why author is getting AV when he tries to call virtual method - he tries to use non-existent VMT.

Comment: +1 I don't know  why this was downvoted since it is the correct answer to that part of the question that is highlighted in bold.

Comment: I had downvoted it for the reason in my comment, but after the edits that no longer applies, so now reverted.

Comment: u can have virtual class methods. Not exactly the same as Self=nil, but close to it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically You can call a method of a nil object. But this practice is very unwanted and dangerous. Avoid it. Rethink your logic. Take a look at class methods.

They will work more like a "static" methods with a lot of limits. You can't acces any properties nor methods that references to properies including Self, nor inherited; because object simply not exists.

Object must be valid before any method call, propery access.

If your function return an object instance that can be nil or in some circumstances your object can be nil, you need to check it before any method call or property access:

```
O := MyFactory.GetObject;
if Assigned(O) then O.MyMethod;
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the Delphi RTL makes use of calling methods on nil object references and encourages this: `TObject.Free`

Comment: Probably TObject.Free is the single place in entire VCL where Self is checked for nil.

Comment: There's at least one more: `TControl.Perform`.

Comment: OK, these functions are very specific. Free is made to avoid double free, and Perform is invoked mostly by Windows messages that not always check for nil. Anyway I think this is not a good approach.

Comment: `Free` isn't made to avoid double free. If `x` isn't `nil`, then `x.Free; x.Free;` will probably fail. `FreeAndNil(x); FreeAndNil(x);` will work, but that would work just as well if it were a `DestroyAndNil` global function. And usually, I'd agree that this is a bad approach, but in this case, `x.ToName(...)` would just be a nicer way to write a `TBase.ToName(x)` static class method; it's just as safe or unsafe.

Comment: O.Free; O := nil; or FreeAndNil. I think You understand what i mean.

Comment: "Double free" usually does refer to `x.Free; x.Free;` (or more commonly the C equivalent), so no, I really didn't, but fair enough if that's what you meant.